# API to construct 802.11 frames in C without managing control fields

Tags: c, wifi

I am trying to build and send 802.11 frames in C. I saw that it is possible to do it with pcap for instance. However, in all example I saw, I have to set myself sequence number and other control fields. So I'm wondering if there is an API that permits to manage all this control part and where I only have to specify addresses ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Which O.S.? Which IDE/toolchain? Which platform?

Comment: Working with gcc on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all what type of packet are you trying to make? Data frames or beacon frames.....

If you are creating from the scratch you need to set all the parameters yourself, i am using this header file
[ieee80211]http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/ieee80211.h
for the 802.11 configuration parameters, and for radiotap headers , you can use 
[radiotap]http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/ieee80211_radiotap.h

i can give you an example code(part of) of creating beacon frames

```
// Add the radiotap header
radiotap->it_version = 0;
radiotap->it_len = sizeof(*radiotap) + sizeof(dataRate);
radiotap->it_present = (1 << IEEE80211_RADIOTAP_RATE);


// Beacon packet flags
dot80211->i_fc[0] = IEEE80211_FC0_VERSION_0 | IEEE80211_FC0_TYPE_MGT | IEEE80211_FC0_SUBTYPE_BEACON;
dot80211->i_fc[1] = IEEE80211_FC1_DIR_NODS;
dot80211->i_dur[0] = 0x0;
dot80211->i_dur[1] = 0x0;
// Destination = broadcast (no retries)
memcpy( dot80211->i_addr1, mac_Destination, IEEE80211_ADDR_LEN );
// Source = our own mac address
memcpy( dot80211->i_addr2, mac_source, IEEE80211_ADDR_LEN );
// BSS = our mac address
memcpy( dot80211->i_addr3, mac_BSSID, IEEE80211_ADDR_LEN );
// Sequence control: Automatically set by the driver

beacon -> beacon_timestamp = TimeStamp;
printf("%"PRIu64,beacon -> beacon_timestamp);
// interval = 100 "time units" = 102.4 ms
// Each time unit is equal to 1024 us
beacon->beacon_interval =  BEACON_INTERVAL;
// capabilities = sent by ESS
//beacon->beacon_capabilities = x0003;
```

For Example :

```
dot80211->i_fc[0] = IEEE80211_FC0_VERSION_0 | IEEE80211_FC0_TYPE_MGT | IEEE80211_FC0_SUBTYPE_BEACON;
```

You can the set the FCS(frame control) like this, which is defined in the header.

My suggestion is to create your own header files or modify it according to your need..

Hope this helps ??

Comment: Hi Warlock,  I actually have a problem using ieee80211.h. It can't be found on linux includes, and when trying to use the file you mentionned alone, a lot of errors appear.

Comment: Hallo , you mean ieee80211.h i pointed to ? can post the error?

Comment: Hello Warlock. I just defined __packed which was not. Now, I am able to send raw frames using pcap_sendpacket. But I have another problem. I tried to specified the data rate on the radiotap header, but the NIC overwrite with always 1Mb/s. Is it possible to avoid this ? Thank you

Comment: you can avoid it..... youcan change the data rate by modifiying your radiotap header ..yes, its possible ! ..

Comment: @Spider it also depends on your kernel version. For Eg:. With ralink adapters , from 4.8 you can change rate. Also with Ath9k PCI drivers..

Mark it as the answer if it helps you solve the problem.

Comment: I figured this out. I use the solution proposed by Warlock. But it appeared that it is better to work with some chipsets than others. For instance, I tried to use broadcom ones and it was not working correctly. Atheros chipset is better, as it allows packet injection while managing itself sequence numbering. Thanks!

Comment: @Spider my pleasure!!